# How to hide ionic tabs on specific pages

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, tabs, hide

I would like to hide or remove the ion tabs from 2 pages of my ionic Angular application and to keep them on the other pages. I tried to dynamicaly change the rootPage, but it didn't work. I'm using Ionic 3.9.2 and Angular 5. How can I hide these tabs only in specific pages ? Thanks in advance !

[image: A page where I want to remove the tabs]

---

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  public rootPage: any = TabsPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, private authService: AuthService) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

---

**app.html**

```
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content></ion-nav>
```

---

**connexion.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Connexion
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding >
  <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="validerConnexion(f)">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary" floating>Adresse mail</ion-label>
      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="email" type="email" name="email" required clearInput="true"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary" floating>Mot de passe</ion-label>
      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="motDePasse" type="password" name="motDePasse" required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <br>

    <button type="submit" ion-button round outline block [disabled]="f.invalid">Se connecter</button>
  </form>

  <button ion-button round outline block type="button" (click)="allerInscription()">S'inscrire</button>
</ion-content>
```

---

**tabs.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { ListeGainsPage } from '../listeGains/listeGains';
import { ListeDepensesPage } from '../listeDepenses/listeDepenses';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-tabs',
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  homePage = HomePage;
  listeGainsPage = ListeGainsPage;
  listeDepensesPage = ListeDepensesPage;
}
```

---

**tabs.html**

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="homePage" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="listeGainsPage" tabIcon="add"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="listeDepensesPage" tabIcon="remove"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: Did you mean to disable the side menu? what tab are you talking about ?

Comment: No, I'm talking about the ion-tabs at the bottom of the page (the ones with the home, add and delete icons)

Comment: well you just need to remove the corresponding html in the page where you don't want them. show us the html if you need help

Comment: I juste added the connexion.html code. It's the page where I would like to remove the tabs. As you can see, there is no html corresponding to the tabs in this page, because I defined the tabs in the app.component.ts and app.html

Comment: I'd suggest that you don't use TabsPage as your rootPage in the app.component. You can add the tab component to the pages where you need it instead.

Comment: Yeah, I think I will do that for the moment, as I don't need them in many pages. Thank you Mehdi !